How can I rewrite and proxy in if statement
I have original url like https://sourceURL/api/fcst/login/login?ProCode=420000, I want config the proxy_pass let it forward to https://targetURL/pestiot/api/fcst/login/login?ProCode=420000。
Here is my current config
location ~ ^/api {
    if ($request_uri ~* "ProCode=420000") {
        rewrite ^(/api/fcst.*)$ /pestiot$1 break;
        proxy_pass https://targetURL;
        break;
    }
}

It seems this always can't work. The pestiot doesn't exist in final target whole url.
Currently,

when I use https://sourceURL/api/fcst/login/login?ProCode=420000 the response is 403 Forbidden.
But https://targetURL/pestiot/api/fcst/login/login?ProCode=420000 works
and https://targetURL/api/fcst/login/login?ProCode=420000 response 404


This config can work. My mistake is this
proxy_set_header Host $http_host;

Since I have proxy to the originalUrl once, so the this sentence should be
proxy_set_header Host $proxy_host;

